# What are (some / the earliest) maid-slapping Isekai Light Novels / Webnovels?

Tags: light-novel-history

I've started ["This Isekai Maid is Forming a Union!"](https://tapas.io/series/This-Isekai-Maid-is-Forming-a-Union/info) which is about stopping:

> Otome protagonists abusing their power, slapping maids, and using them as pawns to do their dirty work.

Given that the only Otome Isekai I'm familiar with is *Tearmoon Empire*, if that even counts, I'm very unprepared to read this, nor do I want to read about such physical abuse, so I'd like some foundational history?

What's the first "Otome Isekai" to feature the protagonist slapping a maid?

Comment: I found manhwa/Korean webtoon [The Duchess' 50 Tea Recipes](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5cdz8ja/the-duchess-50-tea-recipes) (2019) with a hint from [this tweet showing the protagonist slapping a maid](https://twitter.com/piccoma_jp/status/1291708919644119040/photo/4), though not sure if this continues or just once only. That said, the example mentioned in the question is a comic, is the question actually about manga or light novel history?

Comment: @AkiTanaka - Hmm, if you count online web novels as light novels, then yes? It's a webcomic criticizing webnovels, at least, so far. Otherwise I'd like a move to the sci-fi stack, I suppose.